# can I display firebase automatic ID from firebase database on webpage?

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a webpage that takes the data from my firebase database and displays it in a table as shown:

```
var table = document.getElementById("ex-table");
var database = firebase.database().ref().child('users');

database.on('value', function (snapshot) {

    if (snapshot.exists()) {
        var content = '';
        snapshot.forEach(function (data) {
            var val = data.val();
            content += '<tr>';
            content += '<td>' + val.user_ID + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.first_name + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.last_name + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.age + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.additional_info + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.medication_need + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.medication_taken + '</td>';
            content += '<td>' + val.autoID + '</td>';
            content += '</tr>';
        });
        table.innerHTML += content;
    }
});
```

What I am trying to do is also display the automatically generated ID that firebase can do for you. As shown here: 
[image]

How can i add this to my table too? Is there a way to specifiy the Auto ID?

Answer (score 0):

The ID of the node you're querying is not going to be in the object returned by `val()`.  It's going to be in the [DataSnapshot](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot) object that you get from the callback.  Your variable `data` is one of the objects, and it has a property [key](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.database.DataSnapshot#key) that contains what you're looking for.  So, `data.key` is your child node ID.